# How can I center form when opening it in MDI Parent form?

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to solve a problem that occured on my program. All the forms I open from the menu refuse to center based in `MDIParent` form. Since I'm using 2 panels to design a custom toolbar (containing the Close and Minimize buttons) and another panel regarding the menu.

Here is an image to explain my struggle on fixing my problem.

[Image regarding my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HouKu.png)

Things I've tried:

```
Private Sub RegistarDevoluçãoToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RegistarProjetoToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim janela As New frmRegProjeto
    janela.MdiParent = Me
    janela.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
    janela.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not work in the specific case of an MDI child window, use CenterScreen instead.

Comment: Yeah it worked, can you post an answer so I can aprove it for other users? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely you can finish the Q+A you started by yourself now that you know the proper incantation?  You just don't need my help with that.

Comment: Since you had the answer to my question, it doesn't make any sense being myself answering my own question, but as you wish. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer by Hans Passant:

Since it would not work on the specific case of an MDI child window CenterScreen object should get the job done:

```
       Private Sub RegistarDevoluçãoToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RegistarProjetoToolStripMenuItem.Click
         Dim janela As New frmRegProjeto
         janela.MdiParent = Me
         janela.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
         janela.Show()
       End Sub
```